# Calculate percentage with multiple numbers and convert to long

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I have 4 float varaibles which represents the percentage and the sum is 100. I need to convert the float varaibles into long and the total of the LONG percentage should be 100.

If i do the following

```
long longPercentage1 = (long) (floatPercentage1 + 0.5);
long longPercentage2 = (long) (floatPercentage2 + 0.5);
long longPercentage3 = (long) (floatPercentage3 + 0.5);
long longPercentage4 = (long) (floatPercentage4 + 0.5);
```

it works most of the time. But if the floatPercentages are like below:

95.95 -> 96

1.36 -> 1

1.35 -> 1

1.34 -> 1

In the above case, the total comes to 96+1+1+1=99.

Now, in the following set of float values, the total comes to 101.
98.2 -> 98

0.61 -> 1

0.60 -> 1

0.59 -> 1

Really appreciate if anyone could provide a good solution.

Comment: Convert them into `double` instead of `long`.

Comment: There really is no solution. If some percentages are less than one, you really have no choice other than to round them to one or zero. There will always be rounding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tech lead suggested the following approach and I feel its the best possible solution.

1. Perform the calculation without rounding (i.e. without adding 0.5) – but also calculate the remainder as well.
2. Order the remainders (with associations to which values).
3. Then for each % point from the total (without rounding) to 100 take the value for the biggest remainder and add 1 – then remove that value from remainders list. Repeat until 100 is reached.

Answer (score 1):

There's no formula you can just apply to each percentage to convert them to `long` and always end up at 100. But you can decide which if the variables will be adjusted to make sure that you always end up at 100 when you add them together:

```
long longPercentage1 = (long) (floatPercentage1 + 0.5);
long longPercentage2 = (long) (floatPercentage2 + 0.5);
long longPercentage3 = (long) (floatPercentage3 + 0.5);
long longPercentage4 = 100 - longPercentage1 - longPercentage2 - longPercentage3;
```

(I take `longPercentage4` to make up the difference but you could choose any of the four percentages, or even randomly vary which one will make up the difference)

Comment: This will make sure that the total is 100. But this might result in the value 1.01 to be rounded up to 2.

Comment: That's right. The only solution is to make a compromise.